# How to connect RASA bot which we create with rasa init to an user interface that we can run from browser instead of command line?

Tags: javascript, python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I have a basic bot for searching a restaurant, currently I am running it via command line, however I need to connect it with the UI and upload the same in github, I am new to RASA and front end designing part, can someone please help me?

I am looking for basic layout UI using html, css, JS and wish to connect it to RASA Bot

Answer (score 1):

You can either choose to make your own interface for which countless Youtube tutorials exist for different javascript frameworks and libraries, use an existing one with an appropriate license that allows for commercial use (such as this [Vue Beautiful Chat created for Vue.js](https://github.com/mattmezza/vue-beautiful-chat) with this cool [Demo](http://matteo.merola.co/vue-beautiful-chat/)), or use a pre-existing bot framework specifically designed for Rasa integration like [Botfront](https://botfront.io/rasa), which will give you a super neat UI for chatbot design and allow [integration using a widget](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat). The third option is the one that will require the least amount of work and time to achieve while offering insights and analytics into the traffic you are getting. My advice is to take this question to the Rasa Community forums where you are more likely to get more useful answers.